# Access Property of UserControl

Tags: wpf, properties, user-controls, hittest

I have a UserControl which has a `Canvas` as Content. I add basic Path (which has Geometry as Data) to the canvas when constructing the UserControl which I add to the main Canvas.

Then I do a `HitTest` against the main Canvas to get the visible elements. The `HitTest` returns objects of type Path only. I need a way to access other Property/variables of the UserControl that this Path is a member of. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Please show your user control

Answer (score 0):

If your `Canvas` in in the UserControl you can use

```
{Binding Path=propertyyouwant,RelativeSource={RelativeSource
  Mode=FindAncentor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}
```

If your usercontrol nad Canvas are in same Control/Window

```
<YourUserControl Name=myUserControl></YourUserControl>

{Binding Path=propertyyouwant,ElementName=myUserControl}
```